# How to add and substarct value in javascript on keyup event?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do one task using javascript, i have two text boxes one is for total amount and second is for discount and i have value in total amount for example 100 and when i insert discount in discount text box that inserted discount must be subtract from total amount but when i remove that discount that value must be as previous i tried below but it substract value but when it removes discount it does not work please help. Thanks in advance.

```
 $(".form-basic .grand-discount").on('keyup', function () {
     var gross= $('input[name="total_gross_amount"]').val();       
     var totalDiscount = $(this).val();
     if(totalDiscount != '')
     {
        var total=gross-totalDiscount;
     }
     else{
        var total=gross+totalDiscount;
      }
    $('input[name="total_gross_amount"]').val(total);
 });
```

Comment: Store the original gross amount before you modify it

Comment: You have the same exact statement in your `if` and your `else`, for one. Also, please create a [mcve].

Comment: just convert int and check for example var gross= 100;       
     var totalDiscount = 50; var total=parseInt(gross)-parseInt(totalDiscount);

Comment: change `var total=gross+totalDiscount;` to `var total=gross;`

Comment: and if user removes that discount 50 then how it revert totalDiscount     to 100 again

Comment: Setting up the form this way is a bad idea in general because the behavior you want is not well defined. `keyup` will fire when you change `22` to `2` by deleting a character, so what is it supposed to add back? Best do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2x60e483/

Comment: use this code
if(totalDiscount != '')
     {
        var total=parseInt(gross)-parseInt(totalDiscount);
     }
else
{
 var total=gross;
}

Comment: @ChrisG updated your fiddle a bit https://jsfiddle.net/2x60e483/1/

Comment: @seethrough Why? `.val()`already returns `0` if the field is empty. Edit: missed the other changes. Ok.

Comment: Not sure, just as a reflex)) I posted answer mentioning you

Comment: @user7596840 what is wrong with my answer? You said it was working earlier

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".form-basic .grand-discount").on('keyup', function () {
  var gross= $('input[name="total_gross_amount"]').val();       
  var totalDiscount = $(this).val();

 if(totalDiscount.length>0) {
    var total=gross-totalDiscount;
 } else{
    var total=gross;
  }
    $('input[name="total_gross_amount"]').val(total);
 });
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris G proposed in comments and I edited his fiddle(just an example how this could be done, but since the questioner did not provide all info, this is what we have done):

```js
$(".form-basic input").on('input', function() {
  var gross = $('input[name="total_gross_amount"]').val();
  var totalDiscount = $('.grand-discount').val();
  var total = gross - totalDiscount;
  $('#total').html(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-basic">
<input type="number" class="total_gross_amount" name="total_gross_amount">
<input type="number" class="grand-discount" name="grand-discount">
</form>
<p>Total: <span id="total"></span></p>
```

Comment: I posted my solution as comment because strictly speaking, this isn't an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solve your problem, the key is to take gross out of input event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var gross= $('input[name="total_gross_amount"]').val();

$(".form-basic .grand-discount").on('keyup', function () {    

     var totalDiscount = $(this).val();

     if(totalDiscount != '')
     {
        var total=gross-totalDiscount;
     }
     else{
        var total=gross+totalDiscount;
      }
    $('input[name="total_gross_amount"]').val(total);
 });

});
```

ful example here https://jsfiddle.net/wkj0jjvp/

if you want to update gross amount, you should set an event for gross and put inside the discount event.